# Unable to pack Xamarin Studio addin from TeamCity

Tags: xamarin, teamcity, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to run Xamarin Studio add-in packing via bat-file from TeamCity 9.1.4 under Windows 10 (x64):

```
set MDToolFilename="C:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin Studio\bin\mdtool.exe"
set OutputBinaries="..\OutputBinaries\XamarinExtention.dll"
set ArtifactsLocation=..\Artifacts

mkdir %ArtifactsLocation%
%MDToolFilename% setup pack %OutputBinaries% -d:%ArtifactsLocation%
```

but there is error:

```
ERROR: Could not read add-in file: ..\OutputBinaries\XamarinExtention.dll
```

But if I run this bat-file from command line it packs successfully.

It seems that my build agent has no permissions to do something related to addin packing. But it runs under system account.